# Writing functionality for reviews carousel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is the code for my carousel. What I want to accomplish is that when I click on P or N the carousel should move from right to left until it is the end of items. Please anyone help me on this?

**My try:**
I tried to use the position. On click on P or N the position of the whole carousel will shift towards left but it didn't helped.

```css
.carousel_buttons_div {
  text-align: right;
}

.button_previous_box,
.button_next_box {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.carousel_items {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.carousel_items::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.user_review_card {
  min-width: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
}

.company_info {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.company_logo {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

.company_name {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.user_review_text {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.user_info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel_buttons_div">
  <div class="button_previous_box">
    P </div>
  <div class="button_next_box">
    N
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel_items">
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `id's` for the first and last review card and navigate them with a link (ahref).

Here's an example:

```css
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#box {
  width: auto; 
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<a href="#first_review_card">Go to first Card</a><br>
<a href="#last_review_card">Go to last Card</a>


<div id="box">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"id="first_review_card">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" id="last_review_card">
</div>
```

I made the same thing with your code example and added `scroll-behavior: smooth;` and the links for the `P` and `N`:

```css
* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel_buttons_div {
  text-align: right;
}

.button_previous_box,
.button_next_box {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.carousel_items {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.carousel_items::-webkit-scrollbar {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.user_review_card {
  min-width: 33%;
  width: 33%;
  min-height: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
}

.company_info {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.company_logo {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
}

.company_name {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.user_review_text {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.user_info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel_buttons_div">
  <div class="button_previous_box">
    <a href="#first_review_card">P</a> </div>
  <div class="button_next_box">
    <a href="#last_review_card">N</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel_items">
  <div class="user_review_card" id="first_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="user_review_card" id="last_review_card">

    <div class="company_info">
      <div class="company_name">Google India</div>
    </div>

    <div class="user_review_text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ante ornare facilisi ullamcorper a vitae. Mi ante suspendisse suspendisse
    </div>

    <div class="user_info">
      <div class="user_namings">
        <div class="user_name">Harsh Kumar Goyal</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer may be similar to what I wanted but its not. Instead what I wanted was to scroll one by one review and not to the end. Can you help me with that.